# Task Schedule Refusal

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

Although some might not think of it as programming related, it certainly is.  The task Scheduler is a program.   It's launching a process that I have written.   Stating that it's a common problem is not very helpful.

I've set up my own backup procedures, both on a Windows xP machine at home, and on several at the office, where I use the task scheduler to start a backup file which does an xcopy of all files with a newer date than what's on the backup drive TO the backup drive.

Trying to set this up for a friend, I can't get the task scheduler to run, even with his log-in password set up.

He recently got rid of all his Norton anti-virus. . . Is there perhaps a connection?

I also have my own Windows 2000 machine, from which I long ago removed Norton, and the task scheduler doesn't work there either. . . It's not that important there, since there's not much data volatility on that machine anymore.

Comment: Have you made certain that the Task Scheduler service is set automatic instead of manual or disabled?

Comment: Also, are you seeing any entries in the system or application event logs when the service attempts to start?

Comment: Well at least you are trying to make it sound programming related, so at least I know *you* think it's programming related. I still wonder though....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a dumb question - but is his login an administrator on the box?  I would set up a "service account" and give it administrator privileges and run the task under that account.  There may be residual problems with anti-virus or firewall - depending on what he is using now he may have to explicitly authorize that program to run.

Make sure that whatever account is used doesn't have to be logged on to run - though of course machine has to be on.

Answer (score 1):

is the task scheduler service running?  is it set to "Automatic" startup?

to check, open your control panel, go to "Administrative Tools", then "Services".  Find "Task Scheduler" in the list and make sure it's running.

EDIT: also, if the task it set up to run as another user, make sure the "RunAs"(Win2k) or "Secondary Logon" (in XP/Vista) service is running as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by:

1. Replacing the task script to do with a simpler task, that is as independent of privileges etc as possible - just to make sure it starts. A simple dummy task might be to create a directory in the temporary folder.
2. Checking whether the task scheduler will run the process if the "run as" user is logged in
3. Making sure the files/scripts/programs to run are accessible by the SYSTEM user

...and then take it from there.